# How to ensure top-alignment and 16:9 ratio in Beamer

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment

I am creating a beamer presentation and would have the text aligned to the top and an aspect ratio of 16:9. I can obtain both individually using

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{Example}
  Text to align here
  \end{frame}
\end{document
```

or

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{Example}
  Text to align here
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

but I was not able to find out how to combine those effects. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: \documentclass[t,aspectratio=169]{beamer}

Comment: @tomacs : Indeed, that was all that was needed. Please post it as an answer so I can close the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[t,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
```